# How to catch IllegalMonthError

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-dateutil

I'm trying to parse dates from the text, where the date could be in any format. I'm using `dateutil.parser.parse` with `fuzzy=True` argument. But sometimes I get the following error:

```
>>> dateutil.parser.parse("20, 2019", fuzzy=True)
Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py in parse(self, timestr, default, ignoretz, tzinfos, **kwargs)
    654         try:
--> 655             ret = self._build_naive(res, default)
    656         except ValueError as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py in _build_naive(self, res, default)
   1237 
-> 1238             if cday > monthrange(cyear, cmonth)[1]:
   1239                 repl['day'] = monthrange(cyear, cmonth)[1]

/usr/lib64/python3.6/calendar.py in monthrange(year, month)
    122     if not 1 <= month <= 12:
--> 123         raise IllegalMonthError(month)
    124     day1 = weekday(year, month, 1)

IllegalMonthError: bad month number 20; must be 1-12
```

I'm unable to find any way of catching this exception.

Comment: What date should _20, 2019_ refer to?

Answer (score 2):

Dateutil makes use of the [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) module, which is the one raising the exception in the first place. Thus, the solution is to import it and catch:

```py
import calendar
import dateutil

try:
    dateutil.parser.parse("20, 2019", fuzzy=True)
except calendar.IllegalMonthError:
    print("Caught")
```

> Caught

Comment: This is not working for me. I have a string `'Ak-47 Wallpapers 2018'`. I try to parse it in try/except block where in except block I have `calendar.IllegalMonthError` and I still get this error:

`raise IllegalMonthError(month)
calendar.IllegalMonthError: bad month number 2018; must be 1-12`